# Crash using parse username/email login with Facebook login thread 1 signal sigabrt

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-login, sigabrt

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loggedin", sender: self)

    }

    if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil) {

        // User is already logged in, do work such as go to next view controller.

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loggedin", sender: self)

    } else  {

        let loginView : FBSDKLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
        self.view.addSubview(loginView)
        loginView.center = self.view.center
        loginView.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
        loginView.delegate = self

    }

}
```

Error Message in AppDelegate The error says: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT. I have re-entered my connections from the initial login page to the tab bar navigator and I'm still having this issue. Error message in Appdelegate:

```
<i>@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate Thread 1: signal  SIGABRT<i>
```